# Normal Temparature of a Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, temperature

I received my Macbook Pro yesterday. I would like to know what is the normal temperature of a Macbook Pro. Here is mine

[image]

is this okay ?

Answer (score 1):

This response assumes you got the [MacBook Pro 13-Inch "Core i5" 2.4 Late 2013](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.4-13-late-2013-retina-display-specs.html), which was released the day before you asked this question. That device used the 2-Core i5-4258U Intel cpu.

Given [Table 28](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328898#page=77) of the v1 datasheet for [4th Gen Intel Core Processors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/core-technical-resources.html#editorialtable_d89d), it seems the lowest maximum **allowed temperature of the i5-4xxx line is 66.4C, well above your highest listed cpu temperature of 50C**.

Here is a screen shot of the table for convenience:
[image]

Comment: Well done. I was about to answer the temperatures are all perfectly normal and even quite much cooler than the system is designed to run safely and continually under load.

Answer (score -1):

My new MacBook Air sometimes reaches 50°C, so you should be fine.